# ImageMagick installation fail on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, imagemagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick on Linux Mint.

This is the source for installing that I am using[ImageMagick](https://douglascrp.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-install-imagemagick-from-sources.html)

```
sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for imagemagick
```

Is it becuase I am using Mint that it is not working or is it some other reason?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's part of the Linux Mint package system: http://packages.linuxmint.com/search.php?release=any&section=any&keyword=imagemagick

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK ImageMagick is in the main ubuntu repository, mint is build on ubuntu...

- Just install the binaries with 
  `apt-get install imagemagick`
- Or search for the packages
  `apt-cache search ^imagemagick`